¿Que comando puedo usar para ver la llave que une a 2 tablas?
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'bussinessEntityID'.
Este es el error que me aparece a este problema.
SELECT*
FROM HumanResources E
INNER JOIN person P
on  E ModifiedDate = P ModifiedDate ;

El error no va con la consulta. No hay ningún bussinessEntityID en tu consulta. Por favor muestranos el error real y la consulta real. Tu consulta tiene el error que faltan puntas entre los tablas y sus columnas: Debe ser E.ModifiedDate = P.ModifiedDate en vez de E ModifiedDate = P ModifiedDate.

Puedes formatear tu pregunta: Usa los butones para citar y para código en el editor. Entonces hay que añadir etiquetas sql y del DBMS que usas. ¿Cual es?

En tu consulta combinas cada registro de HumanResources con cada registro de person que tiene la misma fecha de modificación (ModifiedDate). Es muy, muy improbable que quieres hacer esto. ¿Qué relación tienen las dos tablas? ¿Es cada persona un recurso humano? En este caso la tabla person va a contener la ID de la tabla HumanResources. Algo como id_human_resource probablemente.

Bienvenida a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Tu pregunta tiene varios problemas. Uno esperaría que en el cuerpo de la pregunta se explique los detalles de lo que dice el título, y que cualquier fragmento de código tenga relación con la explicación que se da, pero en este caso, ninguno de estos parece tener relación con los otros. Ni la explicación abona a lo que se pregunta en el título, ni el código que muestras tiene algo que ver con el mensaje de error que mencionas. Te invito a leer [ask].

Tienes un posible error de sintaxis en la estructura de tu SQL, aquí está corregido:
SELECT * FROM HumanResources.E INNER JOIN person.P ON E.ModifiedDate = P.ModifiedDate;

Por otro lado si sigues teniendo el error aún asegurate que tienes ModifiedDate en la tabla de HumanResources y Person, cabe recalcar que en SQL se deben respetar tanto las mayúsculas y mínusculas en algunos sistemas.
Si estas usando bussinessEntityID para la unión tu SQL quedaría así:
SELECT * FROM HumanResources.E INNER JOIN person.P ON E.bussinessEntityID = P.bussinessEntityID;


La pregunta está mal formulada. El título no tiene nada que ver con la descripción, y el mensaje de error no tiene nada que ver con el código. Es el dilema ¿A cuál de todas ellas respondes?. Por ello se recomienda responder solo a preguntas de buena calidad. Te invito a leer [answer] y, por qué no, [ask] también. Un saludo y bienvenido al sitio!
